# Show the type of notification in inbox

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox, android-app

In the inbox of the app, there is no way to differentiate between comments and answers as is in the global inbox of the website.

Could this be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're correct, the inbox item type was missing from the popup.  This will be corrected in v0.1.18